# What is `tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input` doing?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagenet

`tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input` is supposed to normalized images based on `ImageNet` statistics when we use pre-trained weights. But can someone explain what is it doing exactly (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L158)) and why?

To plot an image after this transformation we may use:

```
plt.imshow(image / 2 + .5)
```

Why does it work?

Comment: It's actually standardizing the images. So its ( pixel_value - mean / std_dev ). You may also observe the specific mean and std dev values in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When run in `"tf"` mode it actuallly expect the input to be uint8 between 0 and 255 and scales it to the range from -1.0 to 1.0. Check the [docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L169-L170) and the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L181-L184).

On other modes it actually scales the data according to hard-coded or estimated mean and std statistics.